# Oracle: show distinct keeping the order

Tags: oracle

I have this table

```
FLIGHT  ROW_NUMBER ORIGIN  DESTINATION
--------------------------------------------------
1111      1        LAX        MIA
1111      2        MIA        SCL 
1111      3        MIA        SCL 
1111      4        SCL        ARG
1111      5        SCL        ARG
1111      6        SCL        ARG
1111      7        SCL        ARG
```

I need to keep the DISTINCT ones, but in the same order that they appear

```
FLIGHT  ROW_NUMBER ORIGIN  DESTINATION
--------------------------------------------------
1111      1        LAX        MIA
1111      2        MIA        SCL 
1111      3        SCL        ARG
```

Comment: In your original you have row_number=3 as 'MIA SCL', but in your 'desired result' you have row_number=3 as 'SCL ARG'.  You'd better explain your data better.

Comment: yes, i need ignore the older row_number  and generate a new one

Comment: that just adds to the confusion.  It appears from your starting point that ROW_NUMBER is a bad name for what is really 'a leg of a flight'.  You need to explain the business meaning of the data and, in business terms, what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; lines #1 - 9 represent sample data (you don't need to type that). The rest uses a subquery which - using the `group by` (because of the `min` function) - returns distinct values. `Row_number` analytic function just displays ordinal numbers for the final result.

If you didn't want to *reorder* them, the subquery would do (but then you'd get ordinal numbers `1, 2, 4` for these sample data).

```
SQL> with test (flight, rn, origin, destination) as
  2    (select 1111, 1, 'LAX', 'MIA' from dual union all
  3     select 1111, 2, 'MIA', 'SCL' from dual union all
  4     select 1111, 3, 'MIA', 'SCL' from dual union all
  5     select 1111, 4, 'SCL', 'ARG' from dual union all
  6     select 1111, 5, 'SCL', 'ARG' from dual union all
  7     select 1111, 6, 'SCL', 'ARG' from dual union all
  8     select 1111, 7, 'SCL', 'ARG' from dual
  9    )
 10  select flight,
 11         row_number() over (partition by flight order by rn) rn,
 12         origin,
 13         destination
 14  from (select flight,
 15               min(rn) rn,
 16               origin,
 17               destination
 18        from test
 19        group by flight, origin, destination
 20       )
 21  order by flight, rn;

    FLIGHT         RN ORI DES
---------- ---------- --- ---
      1111          1 LAX MIA
      1111          2 MIA SCL
      1111          3 SCL ARG

SQL>
```